# Extremely slow samba speeds between two ubuntu systems

Tags: 16.04, networking, samba, file-sharing, shared-folders

I have two ubuntu machines - one operating as samba server with regular config (Ubuntu 16.04) and another one operating as client running ubuntu 14.04. Issue is that I get speed across wireless network around 20kb/s max which is ridiculous. I have tried this site https://calomel.org/samba_optimize.html and everything mentioned in the forums but nothing helps... I noticed that if I share the drive from windows and connect from ubuntu system I get around 1 mb/s which is still really slow but far more decent than 20 kb/s. The drive is NTFS which may slow down the things but not in such scale. Also I observed another behavior - sometimes speed start at 10-20 kb/s and start to slowly increase till 1mb/s max but this takes huge files and a lot of time. Network output is always higher than the write speed. This is my config, any advice and all ideas will be appreciated

Update: By testing and tweaking with options I managed to get it up to 1.2 mb/sec through wireless (card is centrino wireless n 1000) but it still seems slow.

```
# Global parameters
[global]
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
server role = standalone server
map to guest = Bad User
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
unix password sync = Yes
syslog = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072
dns proxy = No
usershare allow guests = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
idmap config * : backend = tdb
use sendfile = Yes

[printers]
comment = All Printers
path = /var/spool/samba
create mask = 0700
printable = Yes
browseable = No

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[SHARED_DRIVE]
path = /media/myuser/SHARED_DRIVE
username = myuser
read only = No
```

Comment: A good first step is to find the bottleneck. [Test the network using iperf3](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/diagnosing-network-speed-with-iperf). Is this result in line with what you expect? 

Test the performance of the drive. Is this in line with what you expect?

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint -  results are awful. 
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.2 sec  9.00 MBytes  7.38 Mbits/sec

Comment: Then I'd suggest you connect your client via cable, and do a samba speed test over cable... That's a good baseline.

Comment: Already did and speed is up to 10 mb/sec. Thank you for the suggestions once more. This is still  around 80 mbps on 300 mpbs card but now it seems more realistic. I will try to tweak samba config some more and try with different laptop to compare speeds.